# Android Studio AVD Emulator Chrome and Play Store missing

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am making my first developer steps on Android.

Trying my first test app on an Android Virtual Device (AVD), I noticed that the device has almost no software on it, there is no Play Store and no Chrome Browser. See Screenshot. I checked all settings up and down but found no way to tweak the basic OS software load. I tried several phone models and API levels, but had no luck.

How can I create a device providing software support similar to a physical device, I do specifically need an Internet browser.

[image: AVD Phone Screenshot]

Comment: Which system image did you choose? Which API level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google Play System Images](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/google-play-system-images-android.html)

When creating the emulator, you need to select and create a system image that contains the playstore.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Play Store column is no longer showing in Android Studio Canary...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky first you have to click at "Create Device" and then you will see the list including "Play Store" column.